How to add substrings to an array?
I want to add to an array the substrings that this loop creates
foreach (char c in chars)
{
    do
    {
        sb.Append(chars[i]);
        choice = sb.ToString();
    } while (c == chars[i]);
    
}

I don't know how to create a loop that adds substrings to an array when the number of substrings is unknown.

C# uses real arrays, in the formal computer science sense. Many other platforms have a dynamic collection and call it an array, but it's not a true array (contiguous fixed size). C# has those, too, but calls them what they are: collections. If your size will vary (ie: you need to append items), you need a collection type, like a List<string>

Where is the "array" you want to add something to? Please [edit] your question to include the surrounding source code (if possible as a [mcve]).
